# UISearchBar - delete row

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, delete-row

I use a tableview and I use a UISearchBar in order to search it. I use the following code when I have to delete a row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

//Get the object to delete from the array.

    Coffee *coffeeObj = nil;

    if (tv == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArrayFiltered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    appDelegate.countRowNumber -= 1;
    NSString *txtmessage2an = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", coffeeObj.price];
    float priceFn = [txtmessage2an floatValue];
    NSString *txtmessage3a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", priceFn];
    float stringDouble1 = [txtmessage3a floatValue];
    float stringDouble2 = appDelegate.countPriceNumber;
    float stringDoubleSum = stringDouble2 - stringDouble1;
    appDelegate.countPriceNumber = stringDoubleSum;
    [appDelegate removeCoffee:coffeeObj];

    //Delete the object from the table.

            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

    if([appDelegate.searchTerm isEqualToString:@"!"]){
        NSLog(@"Not in search...");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(appDelegate.searchTerm);
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:appDelegate.searchTerm];
    }
}
}
```

Basically it works, but when the [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:appDelegate.searchTerm]; is called, then I get the following error:

> 2012-01-05 15:36:05.769 iTaxFriend[9261:707] -[NSIndexPath
>   getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ab490
>   2012-01-05 15:36:05.771 iTaxFriend[9261:707] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSIndexPath getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x3ab490'

I call `[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:appDelegate.searchTerm];` in order to refresh the `UISearch` results. When I remark this line and do it by hand, retyping on the search field, it is working without crashing!

Any ideas how to refresh the results?

Comment: I'm editing your question to remove the Xcode tag and word from the title, as your question has to do with iOS and nothing to do with the Xcode IDE.